# Fun Tan Question

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

Using only trig identities, how would you approach the following question?

> Determine the value of 
>   $$ \prod_{i=1}^{89} \tan i^° = \tan 1^° \cdot \tan 2^° \cdots \tan 89^° $$

Comment: The answer is 1. Wanted to see how different people approached this. I agree with @lab bhattacharjee. However for weaker math learners who might not be able to work confidently with cot I would try this using *tanx=sinx/cosx* as well as *cos(90-x)=sinx*. Each time you'll end up with 1, so obviously when you multiply them together, you get 1.

Comment: @Sid: I have posted an answer that isn't at the other thread, so does this still count as a duplicate?

Comment: @symplectomorphic I am not sure,May be I am not the correct person to answer this. I just flagged it for attention for the mods to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\tan(90^\circ-x)=\cot x=\frac1{\tan x}$$

Set $\displaystyle x=1^\circ,2^\circ,\cdots43^\circ,44^\circ$

or $\displaystyle x=46^\circ,47^\circ,\cdots88^\circ,89^\circ$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the product-to-sum formula $$\tan a\tan b=\frac{\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)}{\cos(a-b)+\cos(a+b)}$$

You can pair up factors in the product where the angles sum to 90 degrees --- 1 and 89, 2 and 88, and so on --- and you get $\cos90=0$ in the numerator and denominator, so that each pairing will take the form of $\cos(a-b)$ over $\cos(a-b)$. This pairing leaves you with a bunch of ones together with $\tan45$, which is also 1. So the product is 1.

Comment: excellent way of looking at it, thank you. :)

Comment: Ironically the stupidly obvious elementary solution didn't jump out at me; I immediately wanted to do something fun with the product-to-sum formulas since the problem involves an interesting product, after all.

Comment: that's great though, I'm busy creating a series of memorandums for questions like this. I thought this site would be useful because most of you do think differently about these types of problems. It makes my work a lot easier and gives me an idea as to how more able learners will approach a thinking question.

Comment: One reason I posted this answer is that too few high school students learn the product-to-sum formulas, and even fewer learn the one for tangent. (If you google "product-to-sum formulas" you'll have to search pretty hard to find a page that gives the tangent formula. Wikipedia does, but most others don't.)

Comment: I know right. In our matric (grade 12) exams the learners are given a page of formulas, the cos and sin product to sum formulas are there but not tan. Here in SA it's an absolute nightmare... during the OBE curriculum they actually took out cot, cosec and sec altogether. You literally didn't see them unless you studied math at university. It wasn't until 2012/13 that they were brought back into the curriculum.

Comment: One suggestion: in future questions you should say you are a teacher and that you know the answer or one solution but are interested in other approaches. That will help to show you aren't just a student looking for homework help.

Comment: I did that in my first post and it got put on hold and got lots of bad rep =.=. I will try another question with a solution now and see if it gets put on hold again.

Comment: If your first post was the one about the minimum of a function, you didn't do that; all you did is post the question. You should make it clear that you already know a solution (even outline it) in the question itself.

Comment: I was just giving you a suggestion! I'm not being impatient. The community has certain guidelines that you will want to follow in order to get good responses. So it's just worth your while to explore what other people do and what makes for a good question.

Comment: I know you are, and I greatly appreciate it and hope you'll answer future questions of mine. :)